# solving trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $16 \cos^2 x + 6 \sin x = 17$ for $0 < x < 2\pi$

Steps:

$16(1-\sin^2x)+6\sin x = 17$

$16\sin^2x-6\sin x + 1 = 0$

let $y = \sin x$

$16y^2 - 6y + 1 = 0$

I was not able to solve this quadratic equation. It has no real roots. What was done incorrectly?

Comment: This equation has only complex roots.

Comment: Your steps are correct. Isn´t there a typo in the book?

Comment: Your title says nothing about what your question really is.  I think the first line of your question should have been the title too.

Comment: Do you have to solve it for reals?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the maximum value of $16\cos^{2}x+6\sin x$ for real $x$ is $256/16 < 17.$ See it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+16cos%5E2%28x%29%2B6sin%28x%29). If you were meant to also try complex $x$ then the condition $0 < x < 2\pi$ is ambiguous. Unless you copied the problem incorrectly, I don't think this is your fault. The error is in the problem itself.

Comment: @DavidK Actually, without the typo it is 265/16 or 16 + 9/16, easily obtained 9/16 from the OP's last quadratic's determinant, and adding 16 to get the original quadratic.

Comment: That's right, WA actually said $265/16$ (still less than $17$), but I accidentally transposed two digits.

Comment: Maybe the 17 should be on the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed your derivation is fine, the quadratic equation $16y^2 - 6y + 1 = 0$ has not real roots indeed $f(y)=16y^2 - 6y + 1$ represents a parabola that opens upward with vertex at $\left(\frac 3{16},\frac 7{16}\right)$.

As an alternative, we have that

$$16 \sin^2 x - 6 \sin x + 1=0 \iff 16 \sin^2 x +1= 6 \sin x $$

which can't have solutions for $\sin x \le 0$ and for $\sin x >0$ by AM-GM

$$16 \sin^2 x +1\ge 8 \sin x>6 \sin x$$